# How to add string to all values in a column of pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Say you have a `DataFrame` with columns;

```
 col_1    col_2 
   1        a
   2        b
   3        c
   4        d
   5        e
```

how would you change the values of `col_2` so that, *new value* = *current value* + `'new'`

Answer (score 16):

Use `+`:

```
df.col_2 = df.col_2 + 'new'
print (df)
   col_1 col_2
0      1  anew
1      2  bnew
2      3  cnew
3      4  dnew
4      5  enew
```

Thanks [hooy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273937/replace-cells-in-column-pandas-python/42273962?noredirect=1#comment71705032_42273962) for another solution:

```
df.col_2 += 'new'
```

Or [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df = df.assign(col_2 = df.col_2 + 'new')
print (df)
   col_1 col_2
0      1  anew
1      2  bnew
2      3  cnew
3      4  dnew
4      5  enew
```

Comment: @jezrael it says that the df has no attribute to assign, and using + doesnt work either. Is there a way to do it through a loop? i.e : `for i in df['col2']:
    .... i+'new' `

Comment: What is `df.info()` ? Maybe need alternative with `[]` like `df['col_2'] = df['col_2'] + 'new'`

Comment: ```df.col_2 += 'new'``` worked for me. Don't know why this answer is not accepted?