# How to create a column of strings, including the values from another column

Tags: python, pandas, string

df =

```
car

big.yellow
small.red
small.black
```

---

1. I want to add each row value between + +. Desired output:

```py
vehicle = 'The vehicle is big.yellow mine'
vehicle = 'The vehicle is small.red mine' 
vehicle = 'The vehicle is small.black mine'
```

2. I need to merge all these string into 1 big string:

```py
final_vehicle = 'The vehicle is big.yellow mine
                 The vehicle is small.red mine
                 The vehicle is small.black mine'
```

But the number of rows in real data is 1000+. How I can speed up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A vectorized approach to create a string for each row value is:

   - [How to add string to all values in a column of pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42273937/7758804) answers the first question, but not the second.
   - `df['col'] = 'string ' + df.car + ' string'`
2. Combine the values into a single long string with one of the following:

   1. [`pandas.DataFrame.to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) as `final = df.veh.to_string(index=False)`
   2. [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) as `final = '\n'.join(df.veh.tolist())`

```py
import pandas as pd
import string  # for test data
import random  # for test data

# create test dataframe
random.seed(365)
df = pd.DataFrame({'car': [random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(10000)]})

# display(df.head())
car
  v
  j
  w
  y
  e

# add the veh column as strings including the value from the car column
df['veh'] = 'The vehicle is ' + df.car + ' mine'

# display(df.head()
car                    veh
  v  The vehicle is v mine
  j  The vehicle is j mine
  w  The vehicle is w mine
  y  The vehicle is y mine
  e  The vehicle is e mine

# create a long string of all the values in veh
final = df.veh.to_string(index=False)

print(final)
The vehicle is v mine
The vehicle is j mine
The vehicle is w mine
The vehicle is y mine
The vehicle is e mine
...
```

Answer (score 0):

this code probably is solve the problem:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'car'])
df['car'] = ['big.yellow', 'small.red', 'small.black']
df['id'] = [1,1,1]

df['new'] = df.groupby('id')['car'].apply(lambda x: ('The vehicle is '+x + '\n').cumsum().str.strip())
df
```

Results:

```
id  car             new
0   1   big.yellow  The vehicle is big.yellow
1   1   small.red   The vehicle is big.yellow\nThe vehicle is smal...
2   1   small.black The vehicle is big.yellow\nThe vehicle is smal...
```

and final:

```
df['new'][len(df)-1]
```

is:

```
'The vehicle is big.yellow\nThe vehicle is small.red\nThe vehicle is small.black'
```